# PHP + Doctrine ORM - Entity with Datetime > 2069

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that fetches datetimes from a oracle database. In some cases (quite often actually, i cant influence that) they are  31-Dec-2099. 
This is returned as 31-Dec-1999 in Symfony.

How can i fix that ? Is there a way to extend the PHP Datetime ? Or extend the Doctrine datetime type ?

Maybe there is a smooth way to check the date with twig filter and add 1000 years if its < 2000 ?

```
DateTime {#989 ▼
  +"date": "1999-12-31 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

I know i could fetch it manually with to_char() but that is not an option.

A few information:

- PHP 7.1.0
- Symfony 3.2.6
- Twig
- Oracle 12g

Thanks in advance and sorry for any language mistakes, im not a native speaker :-)

**EDIT :**

This is my Enitiy field for the date

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="VALIDTO" , type="datetime")
 */
protected $validTo;
```

**EDIT 2:**
My server is *Linux hostname 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 15 15:05:51 UTC 2015 x86_64*

And my php is using all the lib64 files, it should be 64 bit :-)

Comment: Check the format of dates being returned from Oracle. Typically it'll be something like `DD-MON-RR` (e.g., `31-DEC-99`) and PHP will interpret that as 1999, not 2099.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, how could i check that ? The query is done by doctrine , i cant see the raw output :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution ! timclutton was right... i queried the date as string and got it with 31-12-99 form the database.

The solution was to add an event listener

```
 my.oracle.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect, connection: default }
```

The [OracleSessionInit](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Event/Listeners/OracleSessionInit.php) sets the correct NLS Date formats for the session. I finally got my date in a proper format!

Thank you guys for your help !

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that 31-Dec-2099 is outside the range of a 32-bit signed integer. From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> **The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC**. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps
>   ...

But, Symfony/Doctrine would have to check for this and then subtract 100 years to get it to fit. And I'm not sure if they do that deep in their own code --it's possible. Also, your server would have to be 32-bit rather than 64.

> Is there a way to extend the PHP Datetime ?

Oracle docs (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-dates-098686.html) recommend an older PHP Pear library https://pear.php.net/package/Date which does just that.

> Or extend the Doctrine datetime type ?

Is your Doctrine mapping in your entity a DateTime? Are you type hinting the DateTime? If these all check out is there an associated error?

Something else to check. Are you cloning the dates rather than just working off the original? For example, if you have:

```
$date = //get the date from your entity/repository
$date->modify('+some modification');
$newDate = $date //rather than $newDate = new \DateTime($date);
```

This can have unexpected results as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, im not manipulating the data at all. If i query the entity the date field is the shown above.
The range limitation was removed in PHP Version 5.1 as far as i know "However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows)."#

Comment: Well, if your server isn't a 32-bit system and you're not manipulating the date beforehand at all then I'd say Timclutton's answer: some sort of formatting issue where YYYY gets changed to YY.